# AC current measure using CT, 10-bit 200 ksps (mcp3008) or 12-bit 100 ksps (mcp3208), which is better?

Tags: adc, current-measurement

First, sorry for my bad English

I try to build my own wifi energy metter using esp8266 and mcp3208. My electric knowledge is very simple, now my design use mcp3208 to measure AC current from CT, but I read from google that nowaday many households use switch power supply, so to measure more accurate, I need more sample rate. Mcp3008 is lower bit but double samples and lower price but not important than accurate measurement.
So which one is better? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having read a development specification for power-meter IC,I recall the sampling rate for both I and V was 14,000 samples per second.

I suggest the higher resolution ADC that only samples at 100,000 samples per second.

The house wiring provides inductance, to assist in filtering the SwitchReg surges.

Power Meters, to be certified, have dynamic range and accuracy and deadzone requirements.

....If I recall correctly, these meters must NOT have extra counts with ZERO load power.

....Under a mere 10 watt load, the meter must begin incrementing the total-power accumulator. [and probably with some % error, but I don't recall that tolerance; Analog Devices Inc has such ICs; read their datasheets or AppNotes]

....under a 10,000 watt load, the meter must accumulate the total power with less than 1% error. [ or perhaps even more accuracy; but you want to learn, not develop a product to sell.]

Notice the requirement to recognize a 10 watt load, but accurately digitize a 10,000 watt load, requires 10,000 / 10 = 1,000:1 dynamic range or nearly 10 bits.

Thus I suggest you go with the higher resolution ADC.

Comment: Thanks, does 10-bit resolution ADC do this job well? or have to use higher one?

Comment: Thanks very much, I go with your suggestion